# Calling AzureRelay http endpoint with URL length of more then 450 characters results in error 500

Tags: azure-servicebusrelay, azure-relay

Invoking Azure Relay http endpoint with URL length more than 450 characters results into error 500.

Below is the request and error message

```
GET https://tgsrelaydevjha.servicebus.windows.net/LAPTOP-V8FVG8K0//users/MToyYzNlMjU2Ni1mOWJlLTRjYzktOTZkYS00ZThiNWQxMzE0NTU6MDQwMDAwMDA4MjAwZTAwMDc0YzViNzEwMWE4MmUwMDgwMDAwMDAwMDIyY2Y5NjczZTc5MmQ5MDEwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMTAwMDAwMDAzMWQ5YWM5ZjljMWVmNTQ1OGU4MzYxZGNkMDQ3NTE4ZQ/MToyYzNlMjU2Ni1mOWJlLTRjYzktOTZkYS00ZThiNWQxMzE0NTU6MDQwMDAwMDA4MjAwZTAwMDc0YzViNzEwMWE4MmUwMDgwMDAwMDAwMDIyY2Y5NjczZTc5MmQ5MDEwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMTAwMDAwMDAzMWQ5YWM5ZjljMWVmNTQ1OGU4MzYxZGNkMDQ3NTE4 

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
<Code>
<Value>Receiver</Value>
<Subcode>
<Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</Value>
</Subcode>
</Code>
<Reason>
<Text xml:lang="en-US">The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.</Text>
</Reason>
</Fault>
```

Calling AzureRelay http endpoint should invoke the registered HttpListener instead of failing with error 500